# sed permission denied when overwriting file

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to use sed to overwrite my index.php file, but I am getting an error:

```
$ sed -i 's@<head>@<head><script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>@' index.php
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedmZNx8T: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm trying to use it on index.php. I don't know where sedmZNx8T came from

Comment: This is a temporary file created because of the `-i` switch.

Comment: short answer: `$ chmod +w .` and re run `sed`

Answer (score 13):

Really no great answers here. Sorry if thread is dead, it came up in google searches and nothing really answered the question.  Although altendky's answer is sort of the same as mine...  There IS a workaround...find a world writable directory, say /tmp

```
cp /etc/file_to_mod /tmp
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' /tmp/file_to_mod
cat /tmp/file_to_mod >/etc_file_to_mod
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's a workaround solution since the problem come from the write permission on the directory where the file is.

Comment: Can be shortened to: `sed 's/foo/bar/g' /etc/file_to_mod > /etc/file_to_mod`. No need for a temporary file.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you have a permission issue on the `/tmp` dir. (as discussed bellow, you run command in `phpshell`, so `TMP dir` can be setted elsewhere than `/tmp`)

It should looks like :

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwx 333 root root 32768 12 oct.  03:13 /tmp/
```

**explanations**

When invoking `sed` with `-i` flag, `sed` create a temporary file in `/tmp` dir.

---

Proof with `strace` :

```
$ strace -f -e trace=file sed -i 's/a/z/' /tmp/a
execve("/bin/sed", ["sed", "-i", "s/a/z/", "/tmp/a"], [/* 94 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
(...)
open("/tmp/sedPSBTPG", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
rename("/tmp/sedPSBTPG", "/tmp/a")      = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: mine looks like this: drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4.0K Oct 11 21:09 /tmp/  Could you please help me to change it?

Comment: Do you have a $TMPDIR variable ?

Comment: Run the same `strace` command like I does, & paste the output in your post.

Comment: when I type $ echo $TMPDIR I don't get anything

Comment: can you create a file like that ? `touch /tmp/sedmZNx8T`

Comment: I get nothing when i type $ touch /tmp/sedmZNx8T

Comment: So run the `strace` command (install it if needed) and come again. Which distro are you using ?

Comment: I'm trying to execute this though phpshell and cannot use sudo

Comment: So try that : `sed 's/foo/bar/' file > newfile; mv newfile file` and tell me if it works

Comment: cannot create new.php: Permission denied  Apparently I have no write permissions. Is there any other way to replace text in a file?

Comment: `sed` reported an error against `./sedmZNx8T` not `/tmp/sedmZNx8T`.  Do you have write and execute permissions on `.`?  That is, the directory that you are in when you are running `sed` and that contains `index.php`.

Comment: I don't have write access in the directory where index.php is, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can you "sudo" in front of your command. Like
sudo sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/g' /usr/bin/vlc
It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you do not have write access to the directory where `index.php` is stored, then generally you would not have access to `index.php`...?  Assuming this is a 'non-standard' case and you do have write access, `sed -i` is trying to create a temp file in the same directory as `index.php` (just checked and it is the same directory, not the CWD).  Run `sed` without `-i` and end the line with something like `> ~/sed.out` to write the result into a file in your home directory.  Then do what you will with that file.

```
sed 's@<head>@<head><script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>@' index.php > ~/sed.out
```

Be aware that you while you can `cp ~/sed.out index.php` you can not `mv ~/sed.out index.php`.  It would seem that `cp` will put the contents into `index.php` (not modifying the directory you do not have write permissions to) while `mv` tries to change the directory (that you don't have write permissions to).

Comment: The file can be writable for the user even if the directory is not. This isn't non-standard at all. Plenty of reasons why an unprivileged user might need to write a file but not anywhere else in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

check for the `/tmp` folder permission
It should have the following permission

```
drwxrwxrwt   7 root root 4.0K Nov 16 15:06 tmp
```

If it is not ok for you then run the following commands

```
sudo chown root:root /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

once this is done, then put a `sudo` infront of your `sed` command to execute the command as a root user.

This will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

If the use of sed is not a hard requirement, you can probably use the highly ignored command `ed`.

`ed -s index.php <<< $'%s@<head>@<head><script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>@\nwq'`

- The `<command> <<< '<my_input_string>'` construct will pipe '<my_input_string>' into the `<command>` as standard input
- The `$'...'` construct will be parsed for special characters. In this case the `\n` splits the string into two lines
- You can use any construct you want to generate and pipe in the input (echo, printf, etc.)

Standard Input String:

```
%s@<head>@<head><script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>@
wq
```

The first line is your regex search and replace as command for `ed`. The second line tells `ed` to write the changes and quit. You may recognize these commands from vi.

source: [mrbluecoat.blogspot.com/2014/03/in-place-editing-right-way-hint-dont.html](https://mrbluecoat.blogspot.com/2014/03/in-place-editing-right-way-hint-dont.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a much easier solution. You can just print the file to the standard output and then use the `sed` on the stream. Afterward, you just redirect the stream to the same file. Obviously, it is a risky solution cause if you are not 100% sure that you know what you are doing you might lose the entire content of the file in question.

```
cat index.php | sed 's@<head>@<head><script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>@' > index.php
```

Comment: that's dangerous, it's simpler to do it in two steps: 
`CONTENT=$(cat index.php); echo "$CONTENT" | sed ... > index.php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the write permissions to the folder whose file you are changing.

As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36404569/5381704

Comment: How is this different from existing answers?

Comment: In terms of clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :

```
$ chmod +w .
```

And re-run `sed`.

Long answer :

As already said, the problem come from the fact that you don't have write permission on `.` (the current directory from which you run `sed`). If you are on your own machine/drive then you surely can give yourself the permission to write on this directory, that's what the `chmod` do here, unless you want protect it for some reason. However, if your on a network drive and can't change your permission on it then you should ask the one that own the directory to do it or use a workaround solution like copy-modify-past the file somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem under Windows 10. I know, not the OPs question but maybe it helps other people comming from Google.
The solution for me was to remove/move the folder I am working on from the randsomeware protected folders.