# Sed command won's save the substitutioned word in the file

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file named *sara* and in this file. I have the word UNIX somewhere and i want to replace it with linux.

```
sed 's/UNIX/linux/' sara
```

But it only echoes the all content with this change but not saving it in the file sara when i enter with an editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make file be updated, you need to add `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/UNIX/linux/' sara
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello UNIX how are you?
I am pretty fine, UNIX
Great.
```

Without `-i` the substitution is outputed but the file is not changed:

```
$ sed 's/UNIX/Sara/' a
hello Sara how are you?
I am pretty fine, Sara
Great.
$ cat a
hello UNIX how are you?
I am pretty fine, UNIX
Great.
```

With `-i` it is the other way round, file replaced no output:

```
$ sed -i 's/UNIX/Sara/' a
$ cat a
hello Sara how are you?
I am pretty fine, Sara
Great.
```

Comment: explain with example, nice! +1

Comment: thnk you, this way it work only if i am su.. but im trying to do it your way as other user, and all the permissions for this file are opend, yet i am getting: sed: couldn't open temporary file permission denied..

Comment: @user2350095, strange. If you had write permissions for that file, you should be able to modify it. Do you have access to the directory as well? In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850882/sed-permission-denied-when-overwriting-file they discussed this issue.

Comment: Yes indeed, the problam was that i didn't have write permission for everyone, in the directory that contains the file, and now its working fantastic :)

Answer (score 1):

for it to work you will have to add -i to make updated