# sed script - permission denied on temp file

Tags: bash, sed, permissions, permission-denied

I just used a combination of find and sed to replace strings in files of a directory.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's,foo,bar,g' {} +
```

It got the job done. After that I logged off the server (connected via SSH), and then remembered, that I need to run the command again. So I fired the same command with slightly modified find/replace strings, but it did not work anymore giving the following error:

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedPFq4Ck: Permission denied
```

What is wrong now?

FWIW: the file name of the mentioned temporary file changes after each new try.

Answer (score 6):

While editing a file in place, `sed` creates a temporary file, saves the result and then finally `mv` the original file with the temporary one.

The problem is that you don't have write permission in the directory where `sed` is trying to create the temp file.

As the file is `./sedPFq4Ck`, check the permission of the directory where you are running the `find` command.

Comment: @beta Thats an ambiguous question, check the permission of the directory, you don't have write permission in it..perhaps in the first time, you ran it as different user who has permission..

Comment: okay, sorry. my admin changed the permissions between my two attempts. i wasn't aware of this.

Comment: I have a similar sort of a problem where I run sed only but with sudo, and I get a similar message. Any idea why I am not able to do it despite sudo

Answer (score 0):

To complement [heemayl's helpful explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36404569/11942268), if you do not want to modify permissions, you can prevent temporary files by not using `-i` and piping the result of `sed` into the same file again:

```
sed 's,foo,bar,g' /path/to/file > /path/to/file
```