# Why does sed not have permission to open a temporary file when in a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

I am using a git repo that contains a Makefile containing this code in one of the tasks:

```
    echo "${YELLOW}  - Login to Vault${RESET}"
    vault login -method=oidc -namespace=some-namespace --token-only > ~/.vault-token
    echo "${YELLOW}  - Getting temporary Vault token and saving it on .env${RESET}"
    sed -i '' "s/^VAULT_TOKEN=.*/VAULT_TOKEN=$$(cat ~/.vault-token)/g" .env
```

If I run it on my host machine than those commands run OK however when I mount the repo in a docker container (which I do often because I'm a fan of [devcontainers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers)) then the `sed` command fails with:

> sed: can't read s/^VAULT_TOKEN=.*/VAULT_TOKEN=594(cat ~/.vault-token)/g: No such file or directory
> sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedBjCyMp: Permission denied

and I can reproduce the same error simply by running that `sed` command from the command-line instead of from a Makefile.

I am assuming that the second of those error statements ("couldn't open temporary file ./sedBjCyMp: Permission denied") is the real problem here. I have discerned from [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850882/sed-permission-denied-when-overwriting-file) that `sed` is attempting to create a temporary file because of the `-i` switch (which makes sense) and it attempts to do so in **/tmp**. So my question becomes, why is `sed` unable to create a file in **/tmp**? I seem to have all the relevant permissions:

```bash
> ls -l / | grep tmp
drwxrwxrwt - root   22 Sep 12:57 tmp
```

so I can't understand why this command is failing. Clearly its something to do with running in a container (because it works fine outside the container), but I don't know what the reason could be. Any tips about how to diagnose the problem would be appreciated.

---

In response to the comment from Philippe, I have also run:

```bash
> ls -ld .; id
drwxr-xr-x - root 25 Sep 10:50 .
uid=1000(vscode) gid=1000(vscode) groups=1000(vscode),102(docker),998(pipx),999(python)
```

Comment: `./` means you are trying to create the file in the current directory, not /tmp. If the current directory is `/`, for example, then you don't have write permission.

Comment: yes, of course, you're right. Still peculiar that I don't have permission on `./`

Comment: Can you run in the directory inside container this command : `ls -ld .; id` and post result ?

Comment: This is not specific to the question but I am just curious as to why you dont just do `vault login -method=oidc -namespace=some-namespace` that will automatically store the vault token in `~/.vault-token` and it will be available automatically for vault requests as confirmed by the output `Success! You are now authenticated. The token information displayed below is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login" again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.`. I am just trying to understand the use case of also setting as VAULT_TOKEN in the env vars

Comment: Chris Doyle, this is in a repo that I don't own so I'm reluctant to change it.

Comment: @Philippe I have run the command that you suggested and have updated the question above with the output.

Comment: You can see that the current directory is owned by `root` and user `vscode` cannot write to it.

Comment: An answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague figured this out. There was a bug in a previous version of sed which has now been fixed. See https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9647, specifically this part:

> - Noteworthy changes in release 4.8 (2020-01-14) [stable]
>
> ** Bug fixes
>
> "sed -i" now creates temporary files with correct umask (limited to u=rwx).
> Previously sed would incorrectly set umask on temporary files, resulting
> in problems under certain fuse-like file systems.
> [bug introduced in sed 4.2.1]

My colleague fixed by installing sed from source. Here's what he added to the Dockerfile

```
# Install GNU sed from source. This is required to fix the bug in existing version with temporary files creation for sed inplace commands
# Ref: https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9647
RUN sudo apt install -y build-essential \
        && curl -L https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/sed-4.8.tar.gz -o sed-4.8.tar.gz \
        && tar -xzf sed-4.8.tar.gz \
        && cd sed-4.8 \
        && ./configure \
        && make \
        && sudo make install \
        && cd .. \
        && rm -rf sed-4.8.tar.gz sed-4.8
```